# Does a non-invertible matrix A exist where some power of A is the identity matrix?

Tags: matrices

###### Question:

Can a 3x3 non-invertible matrix $A$ exist such that $A^5-A^3=I_3$?

$I_3$ is the 3x3 identity matrix.

Comment: $A^{-1}$ would simply be $A^4-A^2$ so no such matrix can exist.

Comment: @MatthewH. Oh wow, thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that. Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Please ask a good question, if you plan to answer it.  That means abiding by [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.8641).  Else it can and should be appropriately closed as a Problem Statement/ low-quality question, which it currently is.  I say this mostly for any future questions you know the answer to, but post only a problem statement, and proceed to answer the poor posted question.  In part, asking only a problem statement question with no context, gives other users the idea that it's okay.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this solution is right, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

###### My solution:

For $A$ to be non-invertible, it must be the case that $det(A) = 0$.

Then, $det(A^5)$ and $det(A^3)$ must also be $0$ since $det(XY) = det(X) \cdot det(Y)$.

The equation $A^5 - A^3 = I_3$ can be factored as $A^3(A^2 - I_3) = I_3$.

Hence, $det(A^3(A^2-I_3)) = det(I_3) = 1$.

Therefore, $det(A^3) \cdot det(A^2 - I_3) = 1$.

This implies that $det(A^3) \neq 0$.

This contradicts the statement that $det(A^3) = 0$.

Hence, such a matrix cannot exist.